# IntelliJ IDEA doubling certain forms of input (usually copy/paste) and missing some characters while typing

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I've been experiencing some weird issues with IntelliJ IDEA on my Mac. When I copy, cut and paste, the input is usually doubled. So if I have a line like this,

```
println("Awesome message")
```

and then I try to cut the "Awesome message" part, it doubles the cut command (meaning that it actually puts `println()` into my clipboard). Then when I try to paste it, it pastes as `println()println()`.

Rarely, this does *not* happen, but the majority of the time it does.

Additionally when I'm typing the IDE will often not register some of my keystrokes. So if I type something like "class User(@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)", it will often times come out as "(@Id @GentedVale(stragy = GennType.IDENTTY)". This also doesn't happen all the time, just most of the time.

I've tried adding `editor.zero.latency.typing=true` into `idea.properties` but it hasn't helped at all.

Comment: Could you please share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to pinpoint the problem, but after uninstalling IntelliJ IDEA, completely deleting all the software's data on my machine, and then reinstalling, the problem was solved.

Again, to clarify, merely deleting my plugins and reinstalling did *not* fix the problem. I had to follow the instructions written [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519). After doing that, then reinstalling, the problem was solved.